# Text not in the center of page

Tags: sharelatex

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\Huge \hspace{-0.25cm} A LIST
\newline
\LARGE \hspace{-0.25cm} EUROPE
\break
\end{figure}
```

For some reason, the text "A LIST" si not showing on the center of the page, but "EUROPE" is. I still can move the former aroung changing the hspace parameter, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it automatically and still keeping framed within a "figure".

Comment: What for do you use the `\hspace`? `\centering` automatically centers the text within the textwidth.

Comment: Do you want to move text around (away from the center)?  You should use \hspace* at the start or end of line.  (IIRC. \centering sets \leftskip and \rightskip to 0pt plus 1fil.)

Answer (score 1):

The `\centering` command is very particular about grouping, and line breaks (or paragraph endings). The line break or paragraph ending must be inside the centering group.

Here is a MWE that centers both lines of text. To increase the line-to-line separation, you can use something such as `\vspace{12pt}` between the two centering commands. Then, you can add your figure environment, or anything else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\centering\Huge A LIST\par}
{\centering\LARGE EUROPE\par}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `\newline` by `\\`, or simply an empty line:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \Huge A LIST

    \LARGE EUROPE
    \break
\end{figure}
```

Also, the `\hspace` commands are not needed.